# Delete text in quotations after a specific word in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to delete the text including double quotes after the word Description=. Or is there a way i can delete the "text" and the word Description= too and replace it with a blank space.

```
Description="This will have contact details to be stored in Gl tables" 
Description="This service builds the document details in case of change in document. ." 
Description="This method will close the cursor query “q_getM_Lic”"
```

Comment: Which one do you actually want to do? Please clarify.

Comment: Second one will be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I delete the `"text"` and `Description=` and replace it with a blank space?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^Description=".*"`
- Set "Replace with" to  (a single space)
- Enable "Regular expression"

  [image]

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill , but it says that "can't find the text" when i used this expression. I am using Notepad++ v6.1.5, does this expression works for this version too?

Comment: It's a basic regexp and should work for any recent version. It worked here. Please check again you have all the right things ticked in the dialog.

Comment: Remove the `^` from the regexp if `Description` is **not** at the beginning of the line (which is not clear from your question).

Comment: Oh, Sorry for that. Actually it is a large file with 20k lines of code and `Description` comes about 18k times and placing is random. If I am removing `^` from the regexp, it is only replacing the last occurrence of `Description`. And the text between double quotes consists of alphanumeric and special characters. I used the following regexps and it removed about 4k occurrences of `Description`:
`Description="(\w+)"`
`Description="(\s+)"`
`Description="(\W+)"`
`Description="(\S+)"`

Comment: Well it works here with a small test file containing your example text.. I don't know what else to say ... other than your examples are not comprehensive enough ...

Comment: I used this regex and it worked perfectly fine. 

`Description=(["'])(\\?.)*?\1`

Comment: Well your question doesn't mention that you have text starting with single quotes.

Comment: No, it doesn't have a single quote but this is working fine.

Comment: <shrug> You still haven't given us a real data sample. My answer works with your data as presented in the question.